# "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 5 DropDownLists in GridView. I bind the grid with ObjectDataSource and also bind the DropDownLists that belongs to GridView with 5 ObjectDataSources. Every thing is working fine. I capture first DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event in C# and i want to bind 2nd DropDownList. Here is the code that i am using to bind second dropdownlist:

```
protected void Level1DropdownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList level1List = sender as DropDownList;
            if (level1List != null)
            {
                if (level1List.SelectedValue != "0")
                {
                    // Bind Level 2 List
                    GridViewRow currentRow = AnnouncementLevelsGrid.Rows[AnnouncementLevelsGrid.EditIndex];
                    if (currentRow != null)
                    {
                        DropDownList level2List = currentRow.FindControl("Level2DropdownList") as DropDownList;
                        if (level2List != null)
                        {
                            level2List.DataSource = AnnouncementHelper.GetLevel2(level1List.SelectedValue, EmployerHelper.EmployerID);
                            level2List.DataTextField = "Level2";
                            level2List.DataValueField = "Level2Value";
                            level2List.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the asp.net code sample.

```
<asp:GridView ID="AnnouncementLevelsGrid" runat="server" Width="99%" DataSourceID="AnnouncementLevelsDataSource"
                                                    CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="AnnouncementLevelID,AnnouncementId"
                                                    ViewStateMode="Enabled" OnRowCommand="AnnouncementLevelsGrid_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="AnnouncementLevelsGrid_RowDataBound"
                                                    OnRowUpdating="AnnouncementLevelsGrid_RowUpdating">
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
                                                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridRow" />
                                                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternating" />
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Level 1">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Level1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level1").ToString() == "0" ? "ALL" : Eval("Level1") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Level1DropdownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                                                    DataTextField="Level1" DataValueField="Level1Value" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Level1") %>'
                                                                    AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Level1DataSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Level1DropdownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Level 2">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Level2Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level2").ToString() == "0" ? "ALL" : Eval("Level2") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Level2DropdownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                                                    DataTextField="Level2" DataValueField="Level2Value" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Level2") %>'
                                                                    AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Level2DataSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Level2DropdownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Level 3">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Level3Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level3").ToString() == "0" ? "ALL" : Eval("Level3") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Level3DropdownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                                                    DataTextField="Level3" DataValueField="Level3Value" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Level3") %>'
                                                                    AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Level3DataSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Level3DropdownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Level 4">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Level4Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level4").ToString() == "0" ? "ALL" : Eval("Level4") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Level4DropdownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                                                    DataTextField="Level4" DataValueField="Level4Value" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Level4") %>'
                                                                    AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Level4DataSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Level4DropdownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Level 5">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Level5Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level5").ToString() == "0" ? "ALL" : Eval("Level5") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Level5DropdownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                                                    DataTextField="Level5" DataValueField="Level5Value" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Level5") %>'
                                                                    DataSourceID="Level5DataSource">
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18%" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditLink" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                                                    Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit" style="border-width: 0px;" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateLink" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                                                                    Text="Update" ToolTip="Update"><img src="images/Update-Grd.png" alt="Update" style="border-width: 0px;" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                                                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="CancelLink" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                                                    Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel"><img src="images/Cancel-Grd.png" alt="Cancel" style="border-width: 0px;" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                        No Announcements Found.
                                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                </asp:GridView>
                                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AnnouncementLevelsDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAnnouncementLevels"
                                                    TypeName="LinkManagement.DataAccess.AnnouncementHelper" OnSelecting="AnnouncementLevelsDataSource_Selecting">
                                                    <SelectParameters>
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="announcementID" DbType="Int64" />
                                                    </SelectParameters>
                                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Level1DataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLevel1"
                                                    TypeName="LinkManagement.DataAccess.AnnouncementHelper" OnSelecting="Level1DataSource_Selecting">
                                                    <SelectParameters>
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="employerID" DbType="Int64" />
                                                    </SelectParameters>
                                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Level2DataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLevel2"
                                                    TypeName="LinkManagement.DataAccess.AnnouncementHelper" OnSelecting="Level2DataSource_Selecting">
                                                    <SelectParameters>
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="employerID" DbType="Int64" />
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="cc1" DbType="String" />
                                                    </SelectParameters>
                                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Level3DataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLevel3"
                                                    TypeName="LinkManagement.DataAccess.AnnouncementHelper" OnSelecting="Level3DataSource_Selecting">
                                                    <SelectParameters>
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="employerID" DbType="Int64" />
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="cc2" DbType="String" />
                                                    </SelectParameters>
                                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Level4DataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLevel4"
                                                    TypeName="LinkManagement.DataAccess.AnnouncementHelper" OnSelecting="Level4DataSource_Selecting">
                                                    <SelectParameters>
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="employerID" DbType="Int64" />
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="cc3" DbType="String" />
                                                    </SelectParameters>
                                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Level5DataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLevel5"
                                                    TypeName="LinkManagement.DataAccess.AnnouncementHelper" OnSelecting="Level5DataSource_Selecting">
                                                    <SelectParameters>
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="employerID" DbType="Int64" />
                                                        <asp:Parameter Name="cc4" DbType="String" />
                                                    </SelectParameters>
                                                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

When i click edit button in grid view, all the dropdownlists render them in edit mode. They are also populating data correctly. Now when i change the first drop down list item in order to populate the second one, it throws the following exception :

**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.**

Can any body tell me how can i get rid of this problem. Do i need to handle another event of grid to bind the dropdown correctly? Also i want grid row still in edit mode after binding dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to find the problem. I remove the UpdatePanel that surrounds GridView and debug the code. I found that my update function was getting null values except id value. Then i saw the gridview and find that i have selected each dropdownlist value in grid using Eval function which is used for one way databinding(Readonly). I replace it with Bind function and it start working fine.